# running bat file through c#.net code reg

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file

I have run the bat file through dotnet in c# is as below

```
Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "d://s.bat";
                p.Start();
                string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                p.WaitForExit();
```

it works fine while running through dotnet ide.

But my problem is when ever i run the above code after publishing  through IIS it returns me error as

> StandardOut-has-not-been-redirected-or-the-process-hasn-t-started-yet.

can you give me some guide lines to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `RedirectStandardOutput = true`.
Link from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)

Quote from link:

> ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput Property
>   Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the output of an application is written to the Process.StandardOutput stream.

A snippet from my issue to the same problem, when i was making sure our server was starting.

```
if (IsProcessRunning(ServerProcessName)) { return; }
        var p = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                            {
                                FileName = path,
                                RedirectStandardOutput = true, 
                                UseShellExecute = false
                            }
        };
        p.Start();
        var a = "";
        while (!a.Contains("ServicesStarted"))
        {
            a = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this way, to overcome the error:-

```
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
while ( ! p.HasExited ) {
    content.Append(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}
string output = content.ToString();
```

Comment: Instead of the while loop, should use [p.WaitForExit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) or better yet, [p.Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) += delegate{...} if asynchrony is desired.